# How to convert an sha3 hash to an big integer in golang

Tags: go, type-conversion, biginteger, sha-3

I generated a hash value using sha3 and I need to convert it to a big.Int value. Is it possible ? or is there a method to get the integervalue of the hash ?

the following code throws an error that cannot convert type hash.Hash to type int64 :

```
package main 

import (
"math/big"
"golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"
"fmt"

)
func main(){

  chall := "hello word"
  b := byte[](chall)
  h := sha3.New244()
  h.Write(chall)
  h.Write(b)
  d := make([]byte, 16)
  h.Sum(d)
  val := big.NewInt(int64(h))
  fmt.Println(val)

}
```

Comment: What do you consider the "integer value" of 28 bytes?

Comment: can you add clarity to your question. Do you want to save the state of the hash - or just its sum? As @Volker mentioned the `224` (bit) hash - is way too big to fit into 64 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(See Peter's comment for the simpler version of this.)

Interpreting a series of bytes as a `big.Int` is the same as interpreting a series of decimal digits as an arbitrarily large number. For example, to convert the digits 1234 into a "number", you'd do this:

- Start with 0
- Multiply by 10 = 0
- Add 1 = 1
- Multiply by 10 = 10
- Add 2 = 12
- Multiply by 10 = 120
- Add 3 = 123
- Multiply by 10 = 1230
- Add 4 = 1234

The same applies to bytes. The "digits" are just base-256 rather than base-10:

```
val := big.NewInt(0)
for i := 0; i < h.Size(); i++ {
    val.Lsh(val, 8)
    val.Add(val, big.NewInt(int64(d[i])))
}
```

(`Lsh` is a left-shift. Left shifting by 8 bits is the same as multiplying by 256.)

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uAV2j9JOGFp)

Comment: This should be the same as `val := new(big.Int).SetBytes(d)`. ["SetBytes interprets buf as the bytes of a big-endian unsigned integer."](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetBytes)

Comment: @Peter hahaha; yes. I had assumed there was such a method and just couldn't find it (I kept expecting it to be under the New functions rather than a Set function). Thank you. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Your (and Peters) solution is correct iff the bytes of the hash should be interpreted as big-endian unsigned. Litte-endian or signed (in two's complement or any other) or any other interpretation of that bit pattern (e.g. using the popcount as the value) would lead to a different value.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR;

`sha3.New224()` cannot be represented in uint64 type.

---

There are many hash types - and of differing sizes. Go standard library picks a very generic interface to cover all type of hashes: https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash

```
type Hash interface {
    io.Writer
    Sum(b []byte) []byte
    Reset()
    Size() int
    BlockSize() int
}
```

Having said that some Go hash implementations optionally include extra methods like [hash.Hash64](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash64):

```
type Hash64 interface {
    Hash
    Sum64() uint64
}
```

others may implement [encoding.BinaryMarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#BinaryMarshaler):

```
type BinaryMarshaler interface {
    MarshalBinary() (data []byte, err error)
}
```

which one can use to preserve a hash state.

`sha3.New224()`  does not implement the above 2 interfaces, but `crc64` hash does.
To do a runtime check:

```
h64, ok := h.(hash.Hash64)
if ok {
    fmt.Printf("64-bit: %d\n", h64.Sum64())
}
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/uLUfw0gMZka

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
val := new(big.Int).SetBytes(sum)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Qrxo5D5uBjm